# ASP.NET Application lag after post back

Tags: asp.net, ajax

When running my application lately, there is a very long delay after a request is made to the server.  When debugging and stepping through, the code finishes quickly and then a dialog comes up, which I'm assuming is the reason for the lag.  (I've tried a series of other options including disabling usage of ViewState, disabling debugging, installing IE 8 and reinstalling the Ajax Control Toolkit.

The dialog reads as follows:

Find Source: ExtenderControlBase.cs
Original Location: C:\Users\swalther\Projects\AspNetAjax\Releases\30930\AjaxControlToolkitSource\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs

This is strange, since I am not familiar with any user on this machine named swalther (it was reformatted rather recently) and searching my computer for this folder turns up no results.

As usual, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this delay still occur when the Visual Studio debugger is not attached?

Comment: I think that you give us too little informations. I only can suggest to profile your application with any asp.net profile (like ants from red-gate).

Comment: Yes, it still occurs when I detach the application from the debugger.

Comment: Please let me know what other information you need

Comment: I would suggest you try the tracing built in to .NET to see if anything strange is going on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx

Comment: I'm not too familiar with tracing, but after tracing I ended up with a "Argument Exception: General Exception." In the page_load.  Not too helpful, I know.  However, in my program, the lag seems to happen after the server-side code has completed when I am prompted for the ExtenderControlBase file if I'm stepping through or just the lag if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.  (Second time I've answered my own question - go figure.  I'm creating a database of my bugs :) )

Changed this line:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

to this:

```
<ajaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

Looks like you have to use the ajax control toolkit script manager instead of the ASP version.

Answer (score 1):

That reference to swalther refers to the developer who compiled the code in the first place.